# array to filtered based on all values in another array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve the following:

Create a new array with the intersection of the two first arrays

GIVEN:

```
array1: [{ 'id': 2, 'detail': 2 },
         { 'id': 4, 'detail': 5}]

array2:[{ 'no': 1},
        { 'no': 4,},
        {'no' : 7}]
```

GENERATE:

```
array3: [{ 'id': 4, 'detail': 5}]

Because array1.id = array2.no
```

Any suggestion on cleaner/shorter code for this please

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking.

Comment: what's this ? what have you tried ? what's problem ?Moreover your problem is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I efficiently join data of 2 json files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280651/how-can-i-efficiently-join-data-of-2-json-files)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999872/displaying-intersection-of-two-arrays-in-angular-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying intersection of two arrays in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999872/displaying-intersection-of-two-arrays-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array by looking up the needed `id`/`no`.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 2, detail: 2 }, { id: 4, detail: 5 }],
    array2 = [{ no: 1 }, { no: 4 }, { no: 7 }],
    result = array1.filter(function (a) {
        return array2.some(function (b) {
            return a.id === b.no;
        })
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for look up.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 2, detail: 2 }, { id: 4, detail: 5 }],
    array2 = [{ no: 1 }, { no: 4 }, { no: 7 }]
    no = new Set(array2.map(o => o.no)),
    result = array1.filter(o => no.has(o.id));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

from here : [Displaying intersection of two arrays in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999872/displaying-intersection-of-two-arrays-in-angular-js)

```
function(arr1, arr2){
     return arr1.filter(function(n) {
            return arr2.indexOf(n) != -1
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr1 = [{ 'id': 2, 'detail': 2 },
{ 'id': 4, 'detail': 5 }];

let arr2 = [{ 'no': 1 },
{ 'no': 4, },
{ 'no': 7 }];

let result=arr1.filter(function(x){
    for(let  i in arr2){
        if(arr2[i].no==x.id) return true
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(result);
```